# Сжатие изображения png средставми Python

Tags: python, изображения, png, сжатие

**Какими средствами** Python можно сжать(именно сжать, а не уменьшить размер) c потерями изображение формата `png`?
 Можно ли добиться **разной степени сжатия** уже существующего png файла?

Читая документацию Deflate я не смог найти информации об этом, есть ли русскоязычные источники на тему Deflate?

Comment: Я бы предложил изучить алгоритмы сжатия информации (ЛЗВ, например, для начала) и попробовать сделать свой сжиматель ;)

Comment: Сжатие — это и есть уменьшение размера по определению. Так что вопрос непонятен прям совсем

Comment: @andreymal имеется в виду высота и ширина изображения

Comment: @AlexIdest сжатие — это уменьшение высоты и ширины. Уменьшение размера — это тоже уменьшение высоты и ширины. Ваш комментарий не добавил ни капельки понимания

Comment: Если зацепиться за слово Deflate, то гуглите zlib — именно он используется в качестве реализации Deflate в png-картинках

Comment: С практической точки зрения есть [Pillow, который умеет png и zlib](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/handbook/image-file-formats.html#png)